# How does CPU & GPU manufacturers detect if a chip was overclocked for warranty purposes?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, gpu

How does Intel, NVIDIA, AMD/ATI detect if a defective CPU or GPU was ever overclocked for warranty validation purposes?

Can't a software developer [knowledgeable in hardware as well] use that *same* mechanism to design a program that can show second-hand CPU/GPU buyers this pertinent info as well?

**BTW:** I found a [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1011270) here on SU, but it is not sufficiently detailed enough to match this questions premise, and hence warrant the same answers.

Comment: Unless that information is a trade secret someone is willing to divulge, I don't think you're going to get any answers that are different from the question you linked to.

Comment: @MichaelFrank Who knows, maybe a disgruntled former Intel, NVIDIA, or AMD/ATI insider will stumble across this question, and enlighten us all. ;-D There is no doubt that there is a way, but the public just doesn't know about it yet.

Comment: I think it is highly unlikely they know at all. It’s like asking if the CPU has ever overheated. Who knows? Nobody. They know you overclocked the CPU when they ask and you answer. Is there any legitimate reference you can find where someone stated the manufacturer knew they overclocked the CPU and couldn’t get a warranty by simply saying they didn’t overclock it?

Comment: @Appleoddity Nope, no reference. Good point, though! But sadly, if your "[Honor System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honor_system)" idea is right, this opens them up for major scams, and fraud. E.g. suppose a user gets a late model CPU off of eBay used, overclocked, and unstable, or even worse, known to be dead, at an extreme discount (think 95%-98% off retail). He/she could simply buy it, and send it back to Intel or AMD for a shiny brand new one, normally sold at full retail price! Thinking long term, they could even make a business off this notion.

Comment: Not true. Part of obtaining a warranty is showing proof of purchase. Intel does not warranty “used” CPUs. That’s pretty standard practice for any product warranty. https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005721/processors.html

Comment: You're forgetting about "spoof-of-purchase" scenarios, also if the user bought it new, and overclocked it themselves. Fraud, scams, lies and deceit, are commonplace nowadays.